# Setting class on ng-view animate clone

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-view

I am animating my ngView by setting the class on the $routeChangeStart event. It is working as intended, the next page loads up the new class + ng-animate ng-enter ng-enter-active and the previous page clone has the old class + ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active as seen here:

```
<div ng-view class="page1transition ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active" data-ng-animate="2">
<div ng-view class="page2transition ng-animate ng-enter ng-enter-active" data-ng-animate="2">
```

What I want to do is set the previous page's class at the same time as I set the new one, so the transitions would match like this:

```
<div ng-view class="page2transition ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active" data-ng-animate="2">
<div ng-view class="page2transition ng-animate ng-enter ng-enter-active" data-ng-animate="2">
```

I set the animations in the route.

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/statuses/',
        {
            controller: 'StatusesController',
            templateUrl: 'views/statuses/index.html',
            action: 'index',
            title: 'Statuses',
            animation: 'page1transition',
            leftMenuButton: true
        })
        .when('/statuses/new',
        {
            controller: 'StatusesController',
            templateUrl: 'views/statuses/form.html',
            action: 'new',
            animation: 'page3transition',
            title: 'Create Status'
        })
        .when('/statuses/:statusId',
        {
            controller: 'StatusesController',
            templateUrl: 'views/statuses/show.html',
            action: 'show',
            animation: 'page21transition',
            title: 'Status'
        })
```

And apply them in the $routeChangeStart event

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current)
{
    if (current && current.$$route.animation)
    {
        $rootScope.pageClass = next.$$route.animation;
    }
});
```

It seems ng-animate applies which ever animation belongs to the page on enter and exit, however I would want both animations to be based on the next page thats loading. The page1transition leave animation would not really match with the page2transition enter animation, however the page2transition enter animation matches with the page2transition leave animation.

Basically I would like to control the class of both ng-view and the ng-view clone created by ng-animate at the same time. What would be the best way to achieve this?